# How to loop through a list number reference

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to do analysis on yelp reviews, and I'm having trouble looping through multiple reviews. My current code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://www.yelp.com/biz/pizzafire-cleveland')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div', class_='review review--with-sidebar')

records=[]
for result in results:
    a = 0
    while a<21:
        a += 1
    first_result = results[len(a)]   #this is where my code is breaking

#get review
    REV1 = first_result.find('p').text
    print REV1


#get date
    Date = first_result.find('span', class_='rating-qualifier').text
    print Date

#get username
    username = first_result.find('li', class_='user-name').text

#get user location
    userlocation = first_result.find('b').text

#get userrating
    userrating = first_result.find('img', class_='offscreen').get('alt')

#get userstats
    userstats = first_result.find('ul', class_='user-passport-
    stats').text.split()

    friendcount = userstats[0]
    reviewcount = userstats[2]
    photouploadcount = userstats[4]
    yelpstatus = userstats[6]

#get user link
    links=[]
    for a in results[0]('a', href=True):
        links.append(a['href'].split())

    userlink= str(links[0])[4:-2]
    print userlink
```

results[0] refers to the first review. I want it to keep going to review 1, 
2, etc. Does anyone know how to loop through the result in first_result?

Thank you,
Nazar

Comment: What type is `results`? A list of ...? And what are you trying to accomplish with the beginning for loop?

Comment: `results[len(a)] ` should led to `TypeError` as object of type `int` has no `len()`. Do you mean `results[a]`? Also note that `while a<21: a += 1` seem to have no sense. You can just use single line `first_result = results[21]`

Answer (score 0):

It should still be results(a), not results(len(a)):

```
a = 0
while a < 21:
    a += 1
    first_result = results[a]
```

Also, this could be performed better with a for loop:

```
for a in range(21):
    first_result = results[a]
```

However, this will just keep resetting first_result to everything in results. It seems like there are a lot of formatting issues here that need to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

The first few lines of the for loop are redundant. As Evan Nowak suggested,

```
for a in range(21):
    first_result = results[a]
```

would be a good choice. But since `results` is a list, you can shorten it further:

```
for result in result:
```

In your original code, you're not using the `result` variable anywhere other than for assigning it to `first_result`. You can eliminate one of them altogether and perhaps change 'first_result' to 'result' everywhere in your code.

Further, you're hard-coding the value 0 in the inner for loop:

```
for a in results[0]('a', href=True):
    links.append(a['href'].split())
```

I don't think that's intentional. So, if that was overlooked, change it.

Finally, take a look at [The Best of the Best Practices (BOBP) Guide for Python](https://gist.github.com/sloria/7001839) to get more tips on better formatting and general coding practices.